# Multi tenant permission model for a data model and REST controller using Spring (Java)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for examples of a multi-tenant permission model for a RESTful web service and the backend data model. I've built an OAUTH AS and RESTful web service in Java using Spring. Most of the backend is done but now I'm building out the security. What I need is the ability for a user to have different permissions over different objects. For argument sake, lets say there are companies which contain accounts. An authenticated user can have any of these permissions:

- Super user - Full rights to everything
- Company admin rights - Rights to various properties of one or more companies and accounts within that company.
- Account rights - Rights to one of more accounts in a company.

For example, Alice can be a super admin. Bob can have just account rights to ACME-USER1 but have company admin rights to INITECH and all accounts in that company. Bill is just an end user with USER rights over INITECH-USER2.

Initially this concept would be applied to the REST controller. My web service looks something like this:

- POST /company -> Create company -> Super User
- GET /company/{id} -> Get a company -> Super user and company admin for that company
- POST /company/{id}/account -> Create account in company -> Super user and company admin for that company
- GET /company/{id}/account/{acctid} -> Get an account -> super user, company admin and that user

This concept would also extend to the data model. A company say would have the following properties and require the following permissions to modify each properties:

- name -> super admin
- contact_name -> company admin
- contact_email -> company admin
- max_accounts - super admin

The user model would look like this:

- name -> user
- email -> user
- enabled -> company admin
- quota -> super admin

I have created authorities granted by my OAUTH AS such as:

- ROLE_SUPERADMIN
- ROLE_COMPANYADMIN-ACME
- ROLE_COMPANYADMIN-INITECH
- ROLE_USERADMIN-ACME-USER1
- ROLE_USERADMIN-ACME-USER2

Since the roles are not static, I'm don't believe I'm able to use annotations in Java like @Secured or @PreAuthorize. I have written a method that takes the Principal, the company and user as arguments and then generates the role required and checks to see if the user has it. I'm not sure if this is best practice or if there is a "Spring-y" way to do it. As mentioned, I also want this to apply to my data model. I don't want to have to split the entity in to multiple data transfer objects with their own REST controller where the permissions are evaluated.

I also read http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration where they have roles that contain privileges. I like this model because I would create granular permissions like CREATE_COMPANY or EDIT_QUOTA. These would then have to be applied to specific objects.

Any example of projects out there that implement something like this or general thoughts on best practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring SpEL you can receive a reference for any bean in context [Spring Expression Language (SpEL). Bean references.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references) .

In this case, you can use @PreAuthorize annotation. For example:

```
@Component("accessChecker")
public class AccessChecker {
  public boolean hasAccessToCompany(Long companyId) {
    return checkAccessRightsHere(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), companyId);
  }
}  

@Controller
public class CompanyController {
   @RequestMapping("/company/{companyId}")
   @PreAuthorize("@accessChecker.hasAccessToCompany(#companyId)")
   public CompanyDto getCompany(@PathVariable("comapanyId") Long companyId) {

   }
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped for the controller but doesn't help for the property/field level security for the model/DTO.

Comment: @aaronanderson may be it worth to take a look at pre/post filters. they also support SpEL. I would help you more if you provide some code example.

Comment: My project is available here https://github.com/cypherkey/multi-tenant-rest-api. The README describes what I am trying to accomplish. I use PreAuthorize for managing access to the endpoints in the controller and I've create my own ModelMapper annotations on the DTO (see https://github.com/cypherkey/multi-tenant-rest-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redman/client/data/dto/UserDTO.java).